# Exponential Probability Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A college buys 70% of dorm light bulbs from Company A with an exponential lifetime $f_A(x)~ exp(\lambda = 2)$. The other 30% come from company B have lifetime $f_B(x) ~exp(\lambda = 4)$. At the start of a year a light bulb is installed in your dorm room and you are given a spare from the same batch.
a) What is the probability that the bulb will go out during the first quarter of a year (X < 1/4)? Given that it did go out before 1/4 year, what's the probability that is was of type A?
b) Given that the first bulb went out before 1/4 year, what's the probability that the spare bulb will
last more than 3/4 of a year?
c) For a random light bulb on campus, what is the expectation and variance of its lifespan?

From what I have figured out is that:$$P(X<.25)=P(A)*P(X<.25|A)+P(B)*P(X<.25|B)$$
But how does one figure out the $P(X<.25|A)$ or given $B$ parts?
I am also able to figure out that $P(A|X<.25)=\frac{P(A)*P(X<.25|A)}{P(X<.25}$ These parts are all solved from above.

For part b, I believe I need to solve $P(X>.5+.25|X>.25)=\frac{X>.75}{X>.25}=?$

The expectation should be solved by $$E(X)=xf_a(x)+xf_b(x)$$ Correct? By a similar process, we can solve the variance.

Comment: Can you at least find $P\{X < \frac 14\mid A\}$ and $ P\{X < \frac 14\mid B\}$ from the information given to you? Once you have done that, search n your book for "law of total probability"

Comment: aren't they the same thing. And no. I know how to set up conditional probabilities, but other than that no.

Comment: All right, let's try something simpler. The person from Maintenance who installed the bulb told you that it is from Company B. _Now_ can you figure out what is the probability that the bulb fails in the first quarter? The person from Maintenance is actually a math professor who is moonlighting and he tells your roommate that the bulb is from Company A. Can you peek over your roommate's shoulder and tell us what your roommate calculated for the probability that the bulb failed in the first quarter?

Comment: You have referred to the exponential PDFs $f_A$ and $f_B.$ Do you know the CDFs? That is, can you find a function $F_A$ that tells you directly the value of $P(X < .25|A) = P(X \leq .25|A)?$ @DilipSarwate is doing a fine and patient job of leading you on the right path. So I think it is wise to say no more, until you make a bit of progress.

Comment: For comp B: $1-e^{4*.25}$ and For comp A: $1-e^{2*.25}$.

Comment: See my Answer below. Maybe start by finding numerical values for these two probabilities (correct to 5 places for now, round at the very end).

Comment: am I at all correct about the given parts?

Comment: In Comment above you have two exponential expressions. (a) Can you evaluate them? (b) Do you know which probabilities they match? (c) Any idea what $P(A)$ is?

Answer (score 1):

(a) OK, now that you have gotten a start, let's use the law of 
total probability.
$$P(X < .25) = P(\{X < .25\} \cap A) + P(\{X < .25\} \cap B)\\
= P(A)P(X < .25|A) + P(B)P(X < .25|B).$$
The first equation uses the addition rule for the union of disjoint events
and the second uses the general multiplication rule for the
intersection of events. You now know all of the values in the
last expression.

(b) Start by supposing the first bulb is type A. Then use the
"no-memory" property of exponential distributions to find
the probability that the second bulb will last more than 3/4 of
a year.

Then given that the first bulb dies before a quarter year has
passed, what is the probability it is Type A. That is the
inverse probability $P(A|X < .25),$ and you need to use Bayes'
Rule to find it:
$$P(A|X < .25) = P(\{X < .25\}\cap A)/P(X < .25).$$
You just found everything you need in part (a).

Repeat for Type B.
Finally, use the Law of Total Probability again to find 
the total probability of $P(X > .75).$

(c) I will leave this for later. (For you, me, or another Answer.)

Hints: Neither part (a) nor (b) is required. The mean is
relatively easy (weighted average); remember that the mean of an exponential random variable is
the reciprocal of its rate.

For the variance, you need to consider
it represents variability around the mean of the *composite*
collection. Below is a brief simulation in R, based on 10,000 bulbs
on campus, with *exactly* a 70:30 split. (Results are likely accurate to two places but
not necessarily to three.)

```
 n = 10000  #bulbs on campus
 n.a  = .7*n;  n.b = n - n.a  # bulbs of each type
 x.a = rexp(n.a, rate=2);  x.b = rexp(n.b, rate=4)
 x = c(x.a, x.b)  # lifetimes of n bulbs
 mean(x);  var(x)
 ## 0.4253867     
 ## 0.2122199
```

Comment: Please consider editing your question to remove the last sentence saying you have 'no idea'. I hope you do now and and can show at least a little evidence of progress based on Comments and Answer.Maybe a couple of numerical results.

Comment: I edited because I have worked on it and thought about it some more. I am primarily have trouble finding the numbers for what the things are, but the theory makes sense.